# Super and subscript Span is not working properly

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, subscript, superscript

I'm having issues with sub and superscripts with `KitKat`, so I thought of doing a method which given a text, returned the positions where the super and sub scripts are so I could use a `SuperScriptSpan` and a `SubScriptSpan`, since I don't want to make use of the `Html.fromHtml` feature.
My regex's to detect sub and super scripts respectively are:
`[\u2080-\u2089]` and `[\u2070-\u2079]`.
Everything seems to be working correctly except when the render actually happens, since the text doesn't setup properly. In the next screenshot you can see what's happening with the spans:
[image: Wrong spans!]

The code to get the positions is the following:

```
public static ArrayList<int[]> getSuperScripts(String body) {
    ArrayList<int[]> spans = new ArrayList<>();

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\u2070-\\u2079]");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(body);

    // Check all occurrences
    while (matcher.find()) {
        int[] currentSpan = new int[2];
        currentSpan[0] = matcher.start();
        currentSpan[1] = matcher.end();
        spans.add(currentSpan);
    }

    return spans;
}
```

Where the regex changes if it's for subscripts.
Here's the code where I'm setting all the spans:

```
for (int i = 0; i < superScriptSpan.size(); i++) {
        int[] span = superScriptSpan.get(i);
        int superStart = span[0];
        int superEnd = span[1];

        commentsContent.setSpan(new SuperscriptSpan(),
                superStart,
                superEnd, 0);
    }
```

Which again, changes from super to subscript.
Thanks in advance!